# onListItemClick not triggering, Override notation creates an error

Tags: android

I am a very new programmer in general, and have been reading "Beginning Android 4 Games Development" in order to be able to make a simple game for the app store. However, when running this code, the onListItemClick does not trigger when I try to click an the first element in my list, and when I try to insert an override statement, as seen below, an error appears on that line. I attached the Activity the first list item is supposed to go to, and appreciate any help. Thank you very much in advance!

```
package com.example.chapter4androidbasics;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class AndroidBasicsStarter extends ListActivity {

String tests[] = { "LifeCycleTest", "SingleTouchTest", "MultiTouchTest", "KeyTest",
        "AccelerometerTest", "AssetsTest",
        "ExternalStorageTest", "SoundPoolTest", "MediaPlayerTest", "FullScreenTest",
        "RenderViewTest", "ShapeTest", "BitmapTest",
        "FontTest", "SurfaceViewTest" };


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tests));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemCLick(ListView list, View view, int  position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(list, view, position, id);
    String testName = tests[position];
    try {
        Class clazz = Class.forName("com.example.chapter4androidbasics." + testName);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, clazz);
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}

package com.example.chapter4androidbasics;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LifeCycleTest extends Activity{
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
TextView textView;

private void log(String text) {
    Log.d("LifeCycleTest", text);
    builder.append(text);
    builder.append("\n");
    textView.setText(builder.toString());

}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setText(builder.toString());
    setContentView(textView);
    log("created");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    log("resumed");
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    log("paused");

    if (isFinishing()) {
        log("finishing");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your class AndroidBasicsStarter should implement `View.OnClickListener`    i.e `public class AndroidBasicsStarter extends ListActivity implements View.OnClickListener`{

Comment: @Ranjith: `ListActivity` already has a method called `onListItemCLick()` which he is trying to override.

Comment: Maybe do you have some typo? Create array of Class[] test ={ LifeCycleTest.class, SingleTouchTest.class... etc} and use Class object instead of creation it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean and rebuild your project / module. Try closing and then opening it, and lastly try restarting your IDE. These `@Override` annotation errors occur from time to time for no conceivable reason.